# Linux input devices event counter

Tags: linux, input, kernel

I have a task to make some sort of "input devices activity monitor" for my own embedded linux system (based on 2.6.37 kernel). Time from time this monitor should check, were here any input events from touchscreen, buttons, mouse, etc. or not.

I can just read corresponding device files from /dev folder, but these "reads" looks like exclusive, and I cannot read /dev/input/touchscreenX and use this touchscreen in some program at the same time.

I can perform an upgrade (or hack) to all input drivers for my system (just add simple counter for each input_sync and make it readable from sysfs). It should work, but it looks... like a crude hack, yes.

So, how can I monitor input devices activity (from userspace) and use these devices at the same time?

Comment: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Evtest try this

Comment: Evtest uses plain "read" too, so it cannot say anything new.